# Laravel request validation required field if other field values all equal 0

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have an array in my request:

```
['progress_group'] = [0, 0];
['fields'] = [];
```

If all values in `progress_group` have the value '0', then the field: `fields`, should be required. How do I implement this?

I've tried:

```
$rules = [
    'progress_group.*' => 'required',
    //'fields' => 'present',
    'fields.*' => 'required_if:progress_group.*,0'
];
```

So:

```
['progress_group'] = [0, 0];
```

means `fields` is required, but

```
['progress_group'] = [0, 1];
```

means it is not required to fill in..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh sorry, how do I make my validation so it makes the 'fields' is required when all progress_group values equal 0

Comment: don't neglect the "edit" button, it is important that those who open your post see and understand the question as quickly as possible. This time I've edited it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`required_if` compares each element from one array with the one you are comparing with, so it will be `progress_group[0] == fields[0]` and so on for each item.

What you need is I guess a sum of all the values to be either 0 than it is required, and if the sum is bigger than 0 then it is not required.

So you can make a custom rule, or update your validation as such:

```
$total = array_sum(request()->input('progress_group'));

if($total == 0) {
  $rules['fields.*'] = 'required';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you had the right idea to use requiredIf, but I think youmay have got the use and syntax wrong, I think this is correct, or will help you on the way to solving your problem:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'progress_group.*' => 'required',
    'fields' => 'present',
    'fields.*' => Rule:requiredIf:(progress_group.*, 0),
]);
```